# Const and non-const version and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants, c++14

In my problem, I will have a few classes that will share getters and setters (in my case, the `operator()`). Suppose I have the following

```
class Base
{
    public:
        int& operator()() { return value; }
        int operator()() const { return value; }
    protected:
        int value;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        int operator()() const { return value; }
};
```

I expected being able to do something like this :

```
Derived d;
d() = 1;
```

but the compiler complains saying that the expression is not assignable. However, doing this

```
Derived d;
d.Base::operator()() = 1;
```

works correctly. Why is that ? Shouldn't the compiler be able to look up for the member function in the base class ? Is there a solution to avoid rewriting the non-const method is the derived class ?

Comment: For future reference, this is called "Name hiding"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't the compiler be able to look up for the member function in the base class?

Yes, it is possible, but you have to be explicit. For that you can use a `using` declaration, which introduces the operator to the derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        using Base::operator();
        int operator()() const { return value; }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I though about it but it seems that this `using` shadows my derived const version, which is no longer called ([a little example of what I mean](https://code.sololearn.com/cjf4ipg5tFJr/#cpp))

Comment: @DragonRock It does still call the `const` version, as a derived class function always hides a base class function with the same signature. The only problem is that you never call the `const` function, because your instance is not `const`.

Comment: I see, you're right. If I `const_cast` it, [it works as expected](https://code.sololearn.com/cfE5fEz4D0Sf/#cpp). Thanks !